# Can we use RewriteRule for internal paths?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've always seen RewriteRule used for public URL paths, but can we also map the URLs to internal paths?

For example, to redirect all links to my_page.php, is this allowed? :

```
RewriteRule .* /home/yccaucom/public_html/my_page.php [last,noescape]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot redirect to a folder or file that is not within the domain root.

Given that your root folder is:

```
/home/yccaucom/public_html/
```

You can only redirect to what is within `public_html`, for example `public_html/css` or `public_html/some_folder`, you can also make a symbolic link to an internal folder or file and it should work as well.

Given your rule, it would look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_page.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /my_page.php [L,NE]
```

You want the condition to avoid it from falling into a infinite loop.

Or you could check for existent files/folders instead with this 2 conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Basically it says if file or folder does not exist redirect.

If you try to use your rule as it is, it will try to redirect to:

```
/home/yccaucom/public_html/home/yccaucom/public_html/my_page.php
```

However it will most likely not fail since you don't have any verification to stop the loop so it will give you a fail message saying too many redirects or so.

On a deeper look at the rule, this is what happens:

```
10.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2013:05:25:24 --0300] [somedomain.com/sid#7fe8521040e0][rid#7fe85288af18/initial] (3) [perdir /home/account/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/account/public_html/asdasdas2 -> asdasdas2
10.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2013:05:25:24 --0300] [somedomain.com/sid#7fe8521040e0][rid#7fe85288af18/initial] (3) [perdir /home/account/public_html/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'asdasdas2'
10.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2013:05:25:24 --0300] [somedomain.com/sid#7fe8521040e0][rid#7fe85288af18/initial] (2) [perdir /home/account/public_html/] rewrite 'asdasdas2' -> '/home/account/public_html/edit.php'
10.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2013:05:25:24 --0300] [somedomain.com/sid#7fe8521040e0][rid#7fe85288af18/initial] (2) [perdir /home/account/public_html/] trying to replace prefix /home/account/public_html/ with /
10.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2013:05:25:24 --0300] [somedomain.com/sid#7fe8521040e0][rid#7fe85288af18/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: /home/account/public_html/edit.php -> edit.php
10.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2013:05:25:24 --0300] [somedomain.com/sid#7fe8521040e0][rid#7fe85288af18/initial] (4) add subst prefix: edit.php -> /edit.php
10.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2013:05:25:24 --0300] [somedomain.com/sid#7fe8521040e0][rid#7fe85288af18/initial] (1) [perdir /home/account/public_html/] internal redirect with /edit.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
10.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2013:05:25:24 --0300] [somedomain.com/sid#7fe8521040e0][rid#7fe852858798/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /home/account/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/account/public_html/edit.php -> edit.php
10.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2013:05:25:24 --0300] [somedomain.com/sid#7fe8521040e0][rid#7fe852858798/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /home/account/public_html/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'edit.php'
10.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2013:05:25:24 --0300] [somedomain.com/sid#7fe8521040e0][rid#7fe852858798/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir /home/account/public_html/] rewrite 'edit.php' -> '/home/account/public_html/edit.php'
10.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2013:05:25:24 --0300] [somedomain.com/sid#7fe8521040e0][rid#7fe852858798/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /home/account/public_html/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: /home/account/public_html/edit.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

Comment: When you say "within *and above*" what does "and above" mean?

Comment: @Pacerier and above was meant to refer to folders inside public_html, for example `public_html/css`, `public_html/images` those are folders inside it and a symbolic link can be an internal folder `ln -s /test /home/yccaucom/public_html/test/` would make a symbolic link of `/test` inside your `public_html`

Comment: My .htaccess file (*/home/yccaucom/public_html/.htaccess*) has only one line: `RewriteRule .* /home/yccaucom/public_html/my_page.php [last,noescape]`. You say that I will have infinite redirects, but I do not: http://yccau.com/asdasd why do I not get infinite redirects?

Comment: @Pacerier do you have any other .htaccess around?

Comment: @Pacerier I am saying it would fall into an infinite loop because your rule tells to redirect everything to my_page.php, where it would redirect itself to itself that's why.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean? There can only be one .htaccess file in the public_html folder right?

Comment: yes I know you are saying it will enter an infinite loop. But why am I not entering an infinite loop? That's odd.

Comment: You can have multiple .htaccess around other folders

Comment: There is only one .htaccess file in my public_html folder. Why is it not giving infinite redirects?

Comment: @Pacerier would have to look at the debug data to see what its doing. But normally it would do the infinite loop behavior.

Comment: may it be because RewriteRule doesn't apply to internal paths, thus when the URL is mapped to an internal path, RewriteRule doesn't kick in anymore?

Comment: @Pacerier it ignores the rule `initial URL equal rewritten URL: /home/account/public_html/my_page.php [IGNORING REWRITE]` however it does redirect.

Comment: @Pacerier see above on my answer I have updated with what it does, it does the internal redirect, and then when he tries to redirect again it stops because the URL is the same.

Comment: @Pacerier However that only happens because you have the absolute path, if you use /my_page.php you will get the said loop.

Comment: btw how does RewriteRule even know whether we want an internal redirect from an external one? Couldn't /home/yccaucom/public_html be the external URL as well for example http://yccau.com/home/yccaucom/public_html?

Comment: @Pacerier when no redirect flags are define it assumes internal redirect by default, however in some specific cases it will redirect without being internal, for example if you try to do an internal redirect for different domains. Yes you can do a specific external to internal for example `RewriteRule ^home/yccaucom/public_html/?$ /my_page.php [L,NE]` now when you access `yourdomain.com/home/yccaucom/public_html` with and without the ending `/` you will see the content of `my_page.php`.

Comment: You said we need verification to stop the loop or it will give us a fail message saying too many redirects. But from the logs, wouldn't it stop looping by itself due to "initial URL equal rewritten URL"?

Comment: @Pacerier not without using the absolute path because it then doesn't know if the file actually exist or not so it will try to redirect until the limit set. It will match the absolute path against `/` which are obviously different which can also be seen on the debug messages.